# What the RegExp should be?

Tags: regex

I would like to change this (from my `<textarea>`) :

```
1234#123, 123412#123
123123#2 123#123
12334#1
123#9
```

To this :

```
var array = [
"1234#123",
"123412#123",
"123123#2",
"123#123",
"12334#1",
"123#9"
]
```

I tried with this regex `/^(\d+)#(\d+)$/gm;` :

```
1234#2
123#3
```

But not matched on space, comma and new line.

What am I missing ? How should my regex look like ?

PS : I need to capture **two groups of numbers separated by a pound sign**. A single group with a pound sign won't work.

Comment: Remove the `^`  and `$` from your regex, as it will require the line to only contain one match, which is not what you want.

Comment: Remove `^`, `$`, `m`, `(` and `)`. Use `/\d+#\d+/g`.

Comment: Try wait a minute

Comment: Wiktor thank you. It's more easy. Because I think that I must use some think like [ ,\n]

Answer (score 1):

Answer for me it's required to get two group of digits for match them. In this situation I use regexp =>  `/(\d+)#(\d+)/g` that help me.

Comment: Mark what answer??